# Get mimum of group-wise sumup value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and trying to write a query that will return the minimum of a sum-up result.

[image]

In the above table (say UserGame), which number (Column name Number) counts least (not Sum) will be displayed for each GameId. If more than one number has the same count value, number with minimum IID will be displayed.

I am trying to write a query but is not working

```
WITH CTE (GameId, Number, TotalNo, Id)
AS
(
    SELECT GameId, Number, COUNT(Number) AS TotalNo, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY GameId ORDER BY IID DESC) AS Id
    FROM UserGame WHERE GameType = 2
    GROUP BY GameId, Number, IID
),
CTE2
AS
(
    --SELECT GameId, TotalNo, Number
 --   DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY DeptID ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS RowNum
    --FROM CTE

    SELECT GameId, TotalNo, Number,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY GameId ORDER BY GameId DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM CTE
    --GROUP BY GameId, Number
)

SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to find the minimum of a count result for each `GameId` in your `UserGame` table, and if there are multiple numbers with the same count, you want to display the number with the minimum `IID`

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT GameId, Number, COUNT(*) AS TotalNo, MIN(IID) AS MinIID
      FROM UserGame
     WHERE GameType = 2
  GROUP BY GameId, Number
),
RankedCTE AS
(
    SELECT GameId, Number, TotalNo,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GameId ORDER BY TotalNo, MinIID) AS RowNum
      FROM CTE
)
SELECT GameId, Number, TotalNo
  FROM RankedCTE
 WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you include the expect result as well as data in non-image format, but i'm guessing you want to get the rows with the least occured number of counts:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  *, row_number() OVER(partition BY gameid ORDER BY cnt, IID) AS sort -- sort per game order by number of occurances and then by id
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *, count(*) OVER(partition BY gameid, number) AS cnt -- how many times each count occurs
        FROM    (
            VALUES  (1, N'1', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 0)
            ,   (2, N'2', N'20230912005', 2, 1, 3)
            ,   (3, N'3', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 2)
            ,   (4, N'4', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 3)
            ,   (5, N'5', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 7)
            ,   (6, N'6', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 3)
            ,   (7, N'7', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 8)
            ,   (8, N'8', N'20230911158', 2, 1, 3)
            ,   (9, N'9', N'20230912005', 2, 1, 6)
            ,   (10, N'10', N'20230912005', 2, 1, 8)
            ,   (11, N'11', N'20230912005', 2, 1, 1)
            ,   (12, '12',N'20230912005', 2, 1, 4)
        ) t (ID, IID,GameId,GameType,Userid,Number)
        ) x
    ) x
WHERE   x.sort = 1 -- least count occurances
```

It's a multistep process where you first calculate each count occurance, then sort by row number and finally take the first row